# Amazon Report API for Publishers

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reporting, subscription

Has anyone successfully set up the Amazon Report API for publishers. (Link is below)
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/reports-promo/reporting-API.html

I specifically want to request the subscription or the sales report but am unable to achieve this.

I successfully created a security profile and mapped the security profile to the API. I then wrote a program requesting for my LWA Access Token. I sent the token request and I saved the response.

When I request for the sales/subscription report URL I do the following syntax provided on the documentation except I replace the year and the month to the specific time period that I want. Example below:

/api/appstore/download/report/subscription/<2022>/<11>

I then get the following error:

> {"Message":"Request is not authorized."}
> Incorrect Access Key, or the requested report is out of scope (for example, if a marketer requests a payments/agency report).

I don't understand why the request is not authorised when I had just generated an access key or several even and it still doesn't work. I don't think my code is out of scope because the company I work for that has granted / created my security profile has been an amazon partner since 2020.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?